# Accurately lining up AudioSourceNodes for playback

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have various recordings of speech that need to be played back in the browser. Each recording is segmented into 10 second files; each segment is encoded using the Opus format.

Gapless playback is required, so I'm scheduling each `AudioBufferSourceNode` using the following code:

```
const uriArray = [{ index: 5, uri: '.../test001.opus'}, { index: 1, uri: '.../test001.opus' }, ...]

const currentTime = this.gainNode.context.currentTime;
const time = Date.now();

getSounds(uriArray).subscribe(
    next => {
        this.gainNode.context.decodeAudioData(next.data).then(decodedData => {

            // Simple wrapper for AudioBufferNodes
            const sound = new SoundPart(decodedData, this.gainNode, next.index);

            object.data[next.index] = sound;

            console.info(sound.buffer.duration);
            sound.play(currentTime + 0.25 + ((Date.now() - time) / 1000.0) + (next.index * sound.buffer.duration), 0)
        });
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("An error occured");
    }
);
```

I basically fetch a set of files representing a portion of the recording and schedule them according to a pre-specified index whilst taking account of how long it takes to actually download the file. The result is close: the nodes play one after another, but there is some gap between each node. On Chrome, some nodes have no gap between them, while others aren't. On Firefox, there's a noticeable gap. Also, it seems Firefox reports a different duration for the buffer than Chrome, which is why the gap is more noticeable.

Is there anything I'm missing? Gapless playback is one thing, but how can I be certain that it's consistent across browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to ensure that the sample rate of the context is the same as the sample rate of your audio files.  If the rates aren't the same, the audio files get resampled which can result in different durations such that there are gaps.

Comment: In my case, the files have a sample rate of 44.8Khz. I used an `OfflineAudioContext` with a sample rate of 44.1Khz to match Chrome's `AudioContext` sample rate - about the same results. Would the files having a variable bit-rate come into the mix as well?

Comment: 44.8kHz seems rather uncommon.  No, the variable bit rate encoding of the file does not come into play. Note also that the various decoders sometimes won't produce the decoded result that you expect.  Depending on the encoding used and the decoder, the initial and final parts might or might not be included in the result.  This will mess up your timing.